# XSL-Function for lyrics in LilyPond

Tags: xslt

Sorry for my English.
I'm looking for a tip or a function in xsl, that finds out if there is a Space after a tag and if this is true, the function should make something.

Background:
I want to write lyrics of songs in XML, because there are various Musik-Programms, which need a special syntax for working with the lyrics.

For example, the software "SongSheet Generator" needs the syntax:

```
[C]Where have all the [Am]flowers gone
```

for showing (and transposing) the C- an Am-Akkord.

No problem to tag the C and Am like `<akkord>C</akkord>` and write a xsl like

```
<xsl:template match="akkorde">
<span style="color:green">[<xsl:value-of select="." />]</span>
</xsl:template>
```

So long so good (we say in Germany).

Now I want to work with the lyrics in the Notation-Programm "LilyPond", which needs this syntax:

```
Where4 have8 all2 the8 flow-8ers4 gone?2
```

With this writing, the software knows, that the word "Where" is a quarter note, "have" is a 1/8 ... 
(LilyPond sets the word under the appropriate note)

You see, that the word "flowers" is seperated with "-". This is because there are two notes (or two syllables) for the word.
(In Lilypond, every point, comma, Question mark ... is set before the duration of the syllable)

With this background, I want to write my XML like this:

```
<akkord>C</akkord>Where<duration>4</duration> have<duration>8</duration> all<duration>2</duration> the<duration>8</duration> <akkord>Am</akkord>flow<duration>8</duration>ers<duration>4</duration> gone<duration>2</duration>
```

Now I need a XSL-function, that sets the Seperator / hyphen (-) in „flow-8ers4“, if the duration-Tag ist in the word. If the duration-Tag is at the end of the word like „Where4“, then no Seperator should appear.

I thought something like "if the duration-Tag has no space after, then it must be in the word and then the function should put the Seperator / hyphen (-) before the duration-Tag".
But you see above that there is a Question mark at the end of the lyric. So the function must also look, if the first sign is a space or a point, comma ....

Of course, I can also tag the Seperator. But thats more work to do so. I hope a function can make that better / more quickly.

Hope you understand my writing. Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't see tags, it only sees element nodes. The element written as `<duration>4</duration>` has two tags, a start tag and an end tag. Now to understand your question I need to see what you mean by the word "tag", and I think you mean "element node".

You can test whether the current element node is immediately followed by a text node that starts with one of a specific set of characters using the test:

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[translate(substring(.,1,1), ' ?!.,:;()', '') = '']"/>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can generalize the test using regular expressions:

```
matches(., '^\W')
```

tests whether a character is a "non-word" character (a wide class of punctuation characters, separators, and symbols).

Whether this fully satisfies your requirement is hard to tell. For example, it's not clear to me what happens when the `duration` element is immediately followed by another element node, rather than by a text node.